# How to add IntentFilter in an Activity by code?

Tags: java, android, android-2.2-froyo

i have this activity that holds 2 intent filters and my problem is not to use this activity for devices 1.6 and before since i wanted them to use the native contacts.

thanks!

Comment: Here's simialar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937006/adding-intent-to-activity-dynamically. Short answer: alas it's impossible =(

Answer (score 2):

```
public class A extends Activity {
    public A {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(YOUR_BROADCAST);
        filter.addAction(YOUR_BROADCAST_2);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // code here
        }
    };
}
```

First you declare your filter - you can [add multiple actions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#addAction%28java.lang.String%29) to single filter.
Then you need to register it with `BroadcastReceiver` that will serve then upon arrival.

Comment: Question title is "how to add IntentFilter in an Activity code" :) So basically if you need to judge your functionality based on device - this would be the way to go - if you have 1.6 only available, check it in the code and don't register filters.