# Adding intent to activity dynamically

Tags: android

I've got an activity for which I've defined an intent filter statically in AndroidManifest.xml.  I'd like to register additional intents dynamically to that same intent filter in the activity's onStart() method.  Is this possible?  I'm trying to avoid having to implement a separate intent receiver class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible?

No, sorry.

> I'm trying to avoid having to implement a separate intent receiver class.

You have no choice -- an `Intent` used with `sendBroadcast()` is not going to be received by an activity any other way. Do not confuse `startActivity()` `Intents` with `sendBroadcast()` `Intents`.